# Can a param be set as the "same type" as another param in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make two parameters of a function be the exact same dynamically declared type?

```
function compare(a: string | number, b: typeof a): number {
    // ...
}
```

This currently clones `a`'s type onto `b`, so it's effectively also giving `b` the union type of `string | number`, so in other words, it's the same as `(a: string | number, b: string | number)`. But I'm looking for a way to enforce a strict match, where if `a` was a number, `b` must also be a number, and vice versa for strings. Examples:

- `compare(1, 2)` - pass, as expected
- `compare('a', 'b')` - pass, as expected
- `compare(1, 'b')` - pass, but should fail
- `compare('a', 2)` - pass, but should fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to accomplish this:

```
function compare<T = string | number>(a: T, b: T): number {
  // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgQwE4FMA8AKogLyIDOU2MYA5ogD6JgioBGu2AfABSYBciQgBpEbQYQCUglu06IA3gFgAUIkR4oIbEgAMAblUBfVapQYcuHgEZRAJkmGV5rHh4ByTO9Hu27x2Zorla2iL7+Ti6WHl72jkA).

Answer (score 1):

You just need a type parameter:

```
function compare<T extends string | number>(a: T, b: T): number {
  return 0;
}


compare(1, 2) 
compare('a', 'b')
compare(1, 'b') // err
compare('a', 2) // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgQwE4FMA8AKorgB5S5gAmAzojVNjGAOaIA+iYIqARrtgB8ACkwAuRIQA0iXhMIBKCdz4DEAbwCwAKESI8UENiQAGANw6AvjpvaUGHLmEBGGQCYFiHfax5hAckx-GX9efwVvNF8nV0RQ8K87KMcAoPdPIA)